# How can I include a .inc file before hook_node_access runs?

Tags: 7, hooks

I'm currently including a `.inc` file in `hook_init()`, but now need to call a function from that include inside of `hook_node_access()`. I've just discovered that, because `hook_node_access()` runs very early on, my file is not included. I then tried to do it inside of `hook_boot()` because the documentation suggests that it runs sooner, but it's still not available to me. I'm temporarily including the file in my .module outside of any function via a simple

`require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/sites/all/modules/...`

but would prefer not to do it this way.

Comment: Is there any reason you're prefer not to do it that way? It's pretty standard practice as far as I've seen (and use myself)

Comment: I always use `module_load_include()` because it returns the path in a more reliable way, i.e. it might not be in `/sites/all/modules/mymodule`, but could be in `/sites/example.com/all/modules/custom/mymodule` or something like that, and it's nice to just be able to rely on Drupal knowing the right path. However, it's more lean to do the `require_once` myself, so there's a benefit there, too. Given your comment and the answer below, I'll stick with the require_once :)

Comment: One last thing, I've actually used an alternative `index-ajax.php` before which elevates Drupal to a lower bootstrap level to serve custom ajax functions faster (say, if I only need the session bootstrapped), so there are benefits to putting things in `hook_init()` and `hook_boot()` so they're really only needed at the appropriate time, and don't add cruft to requests that don't need them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, using the `require` include to load your file is perfectly sound, I think. Alternatively, you could add the include to the `.info` file of your module and allow it to be loaded on every page.

However, to answer your question: We could implement `hook_hook_info()` from a custom module and add `node_access` as a group for `hook_node_access()`. Now, in our module itself, we can have our access callback in a `mymod.node_access.inc` file.

This is probably not recommended as we are dabbling with core (in a small yet unreliable way) with no real value at all but is a way by which you *could* do it.

Once you have done this, I'd suggest running the entire Drupal core test suite once (at least node module's) to make sure that we are okay.

Comment: I don't fully understand this: "add node_access as a group for hook_node_access()". Does mymod.node_access.inc automatically get called or something? Also, by `hook_hook_info()` do you mean `hook_info()`?

Comment: Here is a link to the documentation of the hook: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_hook_info/7. This should clear it up, I think.